# An application of Lie's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Lie's theorem states that if $L \leq gl(V)$ for a complex vector space $V$ and lie algebra $L$, that if $L$ is solvable then there is a basis for $V$ such that every element in $L$ is represented by an upper triangular matrix.

I want to use Lies theorem to prove the following proposition:

Let $x,y: V \rightarrow V$ be linear maps where $V$ is a complex vector space. Suppose $x,y$ both commute with $[x,y]$, then show that $[x,y]$ is a nilpotent map.

---

So $x[x,y] = [x,y]x$ means that $x^2y -xyx = xyx -yx^2$ and similarly $y[x,y]=[x,y]y$ means that $y^2x - yxy = yxy - xy^2$. I'm not sure if this helps.

The commuting condition also gaurentee's that $[x,[x,y]] = 0$ and likewise for $y$, but we already knew this because there were 2 $x's$ in the inputs and thus it will be zero....

Any help on this one appreciated, thanks

Comment: There is also a proof without Lie's theorem, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455016/if-x-and-y-commute-with-x-y-then-x-y-is-nilpotent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Lie algebra $L \leqslant gl(V)$ generated by $x$ and $y$. See that it is solvable thanks to the assumption. Using Lie's theorem $[x,y]$ will be an upper triangular matrix in some basis with zero diagonal coefficients, hence nilpotent

Comment: Arn't all 2 dimensional Lie algebras solvable?? Here $x$ commutes with $[x,y]$ means $x[x,y] = [x,y]x$, rather than $[x[xy]]=[[xy]x]$ which is always true

Comment: The Lie algebra generated by $x$ and $y$ is not necessarily the vector space generated $x$ and $y$

Comment: Oh right.... Thanks man!!

Comment: I'm trying to find how hypothesis means $L$ is solvable... hmmm.. Is it that obvious??

Comment: Actually the Lie algebra generated by $x$ and $y$ will be the vector space spanned by $x$, $y$ and $[x,y]$ because of the hypothesis (I let you check that) so the derived series is easy to determine