# Prove the $z=[x,y]$ is nilpotent.

Tags: lie-algebras

Suppose there are two elements $x,y\in \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ for $V$ finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field. If both $x,y$ commute with $z=[x,y]$, then how to show that $z$ is nilpotent?

Comment: Presumably you meant to also assume that the field has characteristic $0$? Because otherwise it does not hold.

Comment: yes, you are right!

Comment: Hint: take an eigenspace of $z$ with respect to a nonzero eigenvalue.

Comment: Or use Lie's theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846616/an-application-of-lies-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1).